# How i can find the total number of financial observations within a time frame in R?

Tags: r, date, dplyr

Let's say that we have a data frame of stocks beginning at 2017/01/01 and ending 2022/04/01.

```
library(tidyquant)
symbol = c("DOW","TWTR","FB","GOOG","TSLA","NOK","AMZN","AAPL")
ASSETS = tq_get(symbol, 
                from = "2017-01-01", 
                to = "2022-04-01")
DATAWEB = ASSETS%>%
  select(symbol,date,close,volume)
DATAWEB
```

i want to give a date (any date) and to calculate the annual observations of each stock. Now each year has 365 days but in finance the year has 252 trading days. If i take the percentage change of lag 2 in a year of 252 i will have 250 obs. But in my code below i find 251.(i am searching 1 year of 365 days back).Why ?

```
DATE   = as.Date("2022-01-31",tryFormats = "%Y-%m-%d");DATE # for example 31 of March 

DATAWEB%>%
  dplyr::group_by(symbol, .drop=FALSE)%>%
  dplyr::filter(date <=DATE & date >=(DATE-lubridate::years(1)) )%>%
  dplyr::mutate(y = as.numeric( close - dplyr::lag(close, 2) / close))%>%
  tidyr::drop_na()%>%
  dplyr::select(symbol,date,y)%>%
  dplyr::summarize(OBS1Y = n())


# A tibble: 8 x 2
  symbol OBS1Y
  <chr>  <int>
1 AAPL     251
2 AMZN     251
3 DOW      251
4 FB       251
5 GOOG     251
6 NOK      251
7 TSLA     251
8 TWTR     251
```

The problem is that if i ago back 252 obs i will result to 250:

```
DATAWEB%>%
  dplyr::group_by(symbol, .drop=FALSE)%>%
  dplyr::filter(date <=DATE)%>%
  dplyr::slice_tail(n=252)%>%
  dplyr::mutate(y = as.numeric( close - dplyr::lag(close, 2) / close))%>%
  tidyr::drop_na()%>%
  dplyr::select(symbol,date,y)%>%
  dplyr::summarize(OBS1Y = n())



# A tibble: 8 x 2
  symbol OBS1Y
  <chr>  <int>
1 AAPL     250
2 AMZN     250
3 DOW      250
4 FB       250
5 GOOG     250
6 NOK      250
7 TSLA     250
8 TWTR     250
```

but it might NOT go exactly one year back but less (for example AAPL goes 252 obs back and stops later than one year):

```
# A tibble: 250 x 3
   symbol date           y
   <chr>  <date>     <dbl>
 1 AAPL   2021-02-04  136.
 2 AAPL   2021-02-05  136.
 3 AAPL   2021-02-08  136.
 4 AAPL   2021-02-09  135.
 5 AAPL   2021-02-10  134.
 6 AAPL   2021-02-11  134.
 7 AAPL   2021-02-12  134.
 8 AAPL   2021-02-16  132.
 9 AAPL   2021-02-17  130.
10 AAPL   2021-02-18  129.
# ... with 240 more rows
# i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

My question is: How can i fix this ? I want to give any date that i want and (probably is the last day of each month) and go back one year that has 250 observations (252 but excluding NA's will result to 250).

Any help i would appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is. If you use 2022-01-31 as the DATE, then you have 253 observations for each symbol between 2021-02-01 and 2022-01-31, inclusive.  For any one year period you choose, the number of trading days in the past year (and remember a year is NOT always 365 days), will not be constant.

Comment: I believe the number of trading days in 2022 is only 250 days and in 2021 251 days. See: https://us-public-holidays.com/new-york-stock-exchange/2021

Comment: Just to better understand: "I want to give any date that i want and (probably is the last day of each month) and go back one year that has 250 observations" you mean that from tq_get you select a specific date and find from that point the prices of the stocks you chose in a monthly interval?

Comment: if you just want the last 252 observations prior to and including a given date for each symbol, then you can just pull that directly, filtering by date, arrange by date, group by symbol, and slice_tail(n=252)

Comment: thank you all for your useful comments. I think that the ideal solution would be to index back 252 observations with `slice_tail(n=252)` .I cannot find data to demonstrate you the following: In a year of 252 trading days some stocks which are new entries will not have 252 obs because they are new.Some other might  have 0 volume.Both cases must be included and for them the total sum of annual obs will not be 250 as for the big companies.

Comment: Leap years and January 1 being a different day possibly every year (accordingly) are the issues.